# Android dumpsys code flow

Tags: android, adb, android-source, android-debug

I want to know how exactly the

```
adb shell dumpsys
```

works and how is it implemented in AOSP. 
So far my understanding is that most of the system services implements the

```
@Override
public void dump()
```

function and use that. But which java class own this function, to which this @Override points to?

Answer (score 4):

When `adb shell dumpsys` is invoked a native dumpsys binary is executed which asks the `IServiceManager` for a list of all **system services** (services which are built-in to Android) and invokes the [`IBinder#dump(FileDescriptor fd, String[] args)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.html#dump(java.io.FileDescriptor,%20java.lang.String[])) method on each one, with the FileDescriptor set to `STDOUT`. See [`dumpsys.cpp`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/lollipop-mr1-release/cmds/dumpsys/dumpsys.cpp) in the platform for more information.

When `adb shell dumpsys activity service <yourservicename>` is used it invokes the same dump method mentioned above on the `ActivityManagerService` with the arguments `service <yourservicename>` which then passes along the dump request to your service (if it is running) by calling [`Service#dump(FileDescriptor fd, PrintWriter writer, String[] args)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#dump(java.io.FileDescriptor,%20java.io.PrintWriter,%20java.lang.String[])).

Comment: @satur9nine ok so i can override `Service#dump` method and dump my service state (`dumpsys activity service <myservicename>`), but is there any way to dump my Binders's state? i have a `Binde`r with overrode `Binder#dump(FileDescriptor fd, PrintWriter fout, String[] args)` method but cannot see any way to invoke it from `dumpsys`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to dump. When used by non-system services the `IBinder` class is just meant to be passed to clients to facilitate communication, it shouldn't really have any state for you dump. **System services** are implemented differently from regular application services and hence use a different dump method.